# How to implement Excel MROUND() function in Java using BigDecimal instead of double

Tags: java, math, numbers, rounding, bigdecimal

How can I round to a specific multiple in Java? In excel there is the mround function which allows for easy rounding to a specified multiple like so:

```
mRound(variable,multiple)
```

e.g. This is how the Java function should work for given 'Number' and 'Factor'.
To get more test data, just add below 'Number' and 'Factor' columns in MS Excel and in the next column use excel's built in MROUND function as =MROUND(Number, Factor)

[image]

I know how it can be done with double, but I **need a solution with BigDecimal** as I am working with financial data.

Solution with double -

```
double mRound(double value, double factor) {
    return Math.round(value / factor) * factor;
}
```

**This is how excel MROUND function works -**
The MROUND Excel function rounds the number to the nearest multiple of the provided number. You must be thinking about how Excel knows whether to round up or round down. It depends on the result of the division.

For example 16 / 3 = 5.33333, here decimal value is less than 0.5 so result of nearest multiple value of number 3 is 5, so 3 * 5 = 15. Here, Excel **rounds down** the value if the decimal value is less than 0.5.

Similarly, look at this equation 20 / 3 = 6.66667. In this equation, the decimal value is greater than 0.5, so Excel **rounds up** the result to 7, so 3 * 7 = 21.

For more details on how MROUND works, refer - https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/mround-in-excel/

Comment: I tried using divide(). round(), multiply() but they are not helping as expected. This is how MROUND function works in excel https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/mround-in-excel/

Comment: apologies. I have added more details in the question. Above solution by @user85421 does not work if we change the factor value.

Comment: I am really not sure on that. However if you user above 'Number' and 'Factor' column values in MS excel and use excel's MROUND function, you will get above results. e.g. MROUND(532.785, 0.01) = 532.78

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BigDecimal` class offers all needed methods to do the same as `Math.round(value / factor) * factor;` - rounding is a bit tricky, since `BigDecimal#round` is using `MathContext` which requires a precision: the total number of digits, not the number of digits of the fractional part. But `BigDecimal#setScale` is a replacement for `Math#round`.

Assuming that both `values` and `factor` are already `BigDecimal`, we would write your method as:

```
static BigDecimal mRound(BigDecimal value, BigDecimal factor) {
    return 
        value
        .divide(factor)
        .setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
        .multiply(factor);
}
```

I believe the `divde()` and `multiply()` methods do not need more explanation, for details refer to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) of `BigDecimal`.

The `setScale()` methods is used to round the number. As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#scale()): "the scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point."
We used:

- `scale: 0` since we want no decimal digits;
- `roundingMode: HALF_UP` since we want `0.5` or greater rounded up
  again, see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html) for the different modes.

To remove the trailing zeros from the result, use the `stripTrailingZeros()` method after multiplying:

```
return 
    ...
    .multiply(factor)
    .stripTrailingZeros();
```

Please be aware that using `new BigDecimal(double)` can cause problems since `double` is not an exact representation - use `new BigDecimal(String)` instead!
For example, `new BigDecimal(1.2)` results in `1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875`.

---

#### Testing

```
List<List<BigDecimal>> data = """
    523.235  0.05
    523.265  0.05
    523.205  0.05
    523.735  0.05
    523.785  0.05
    523.75   0.05
    523.705  0.05
    15       8
    17       5
    523.235  0.01
    523.265  0.01
    523.205  0.01
    523.735  0.01
    523.785  0.01
    523.75   0.01
    523.705  0.01
    """
.lines()
.map(line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\h+")).map(BigDecimal::new).toList())
.toList();
for (var test : data) {
    var value = test.get(0);
    var factor = test.get(1);
    var result = mRound(value, factor);
    System.out.printf("%10s  %5s  %10s%n", value, factor, result);
}
```

##### Result

```
   523.235   0.05      523.25
   523.265   0.05      523.25
   523.205   0.05      523.20
   523.735   0.05      523.75
   523.785   0.05      523.80
    523.75   0.05      523.75
   523.705   0.05      523.70
        15      8          16
        17      5          15
   523.235   0.01      523.24
   523.265   0.01      523.27
   523.205   0.01      523.21
   523.735   0.01      523.74
   523.785   0.01      523.79
    523.75   0.01      523.75
   523.705   0.01      523.71
```

Note the result for `523.785  0.01` does not match the given input image - I wonder if that is a bug in Excel (is it using `double`?) :-/